# Does Syncfusion Dashboard web data source support POST http methods?

Tags: rest, datasource, dashboard, syncfusion, bigdata

Does **Syncfusion Dashboard** web data source support **POST** http methods?
If yes, so how set it up?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Post requests additional data from client to server in the message body, where message body will be like JSON, XML, TEXT etc. This may result in the creation of a new resource or the updates of existing resources or both. In contrast, HTTP Get requests include all required data in the URL. So we support HTTP Get method since POST method is not valid use case.

Regards,
Umapathy S.